# Reduce the laptop weight falls on shoulder when carring

Tags: moving

I don't like to use a back pack instead of the side bag supplied by laptop it self. But when I carry the laptop in a back pack for a long distance, I feel a pain on my shoulders. How do I reduce the pain by doing a hack on placing laptop in the bag?

Answer (score 2):

***What might help you is:***

- Adding cushions to your backpack or shoulder bag straps. This can be done by getting softer straps or sewing softer materials into the strap, also making the strap broader helps. The broader the strap the more the weight is displaced, there are usually devices for this already on the strap.
- Get a waist belt. A waist belt for your back pack helps it support the weight instead of just lying directly on your shoulders.

***Usually a shoulder bag has more than one handle, it has a longer shoulder strap and a shorter hand strap, by using both of them you lessen the weight directly on you shoulder. Also, switch sides that hold the bag frequently and avoid narrow straps, try broader padded ones.***

---

You may want to invest in a new back pack that is made to hold a appreciable amount of weight. This way the backpack is stronger and more comrfortable.

[Fitting you backpack.](https://www.whitemountain.com.au/fitting_backpacks/index.html)

[hartchirocenter.com](http://www.hartchirocenter.com/backpack-safety-how-to-wear-your-backpack-for-a-healthy-back)

> The backpack should fit so the bulk of the weight is transferred from
>   the shoulders to the hips and lower back. Shoulder straps that are too
>   loose can cause the backpack to dangle uncomfortably, and cause
>   misalignment and pain.
>
> Choose a backpack with a lumbar support. The lumbar cushion will
>   redistribute weight to the lower extremities, creating a fulcrum that
>   facilitates an upright standing position and good posture that is
>   essential for proper spinal health.

Answer (score 1):

Waist, chest, and hip belts on your backpack take significant stress off your shoulders no matter how much weight you are carrying.